# How can I install snappy by choco?

Tags: windows, github-actions, snappy, choco

I want to build a GitHub action. Since I'm not familiar with Windows platform, I use choco to install the dependencies.

But I cannot find snappy on the choco.

Or how to deal with the dependencies in GitHub Action Windows Platform?

P.S. the ‘snappy-driver’ below does not work.

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@vmaster

    - name: Install zstd
      run: choco install -y zstandard

    - name: Install snappy
      run: choco install -y snappy-driver-installer-origin # does't work
```

Comment: `snappy-driver-installer-origin` is deprecated. use: `choco install -y sdio`

Comment: Thanks so much! And one more question, could I use this to install snappy in choco?